# Limitation of part of transaction in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I've got a procedure which refresh data in some tables.
During updating materialized views I'd like to limit
part of procedure in 1 hour.
For example here is simple plan of procedure with approximate
time of duration:

1. Load data in temp tables - 2 hours
2. Refreshing materialized views - 1 hour
3. Finishing of procedure - 30 minutes.

The second block 'Refreshing materialized views' consists of several operations
and I need that block to fail procedure if it lasts more then 1 hour.
For example if in this block there are 3 materialized views to update and
first updates in 20 minutes, second 30 minutes and the third 5 minutes (sum is 55)
then its ok, procedure may go further. If first views updates in 20 minutes, second 30 minutes and the third 15 minutes (sum is 1 hour and 5 minutes) then its more then 1 hour limit
and error or rise notice must be called.

The procedure is written in Pl/pgsql

Postgres 13 version.

In all my point is to control the execution time of individual queries inside a procedure. Is it really possible?

Comment: Check the time after each step and compare to the start time? What exactly is the question?

Comment: the question is not to wait when time will be more 1 hour. And terminate while postgres is trying to take lock when time become over 1 hour

Comment: My point is to control the execution time of individual queries inside a procedure.
Is it really possible?

Comment: You could set the statement_timeout, but that works for the entire procedure. I wouldn't use it: Your statement would have taken 61 minutes, but you killed it after 60. That leaves you with outdated results in the materialized views. This approach is not going to solve your problem, it just creates new ones.